# Is there any method to determine from a diff file whether a file has more content after the diff

Tags: git, git-diff

For example, here is a simple diff:

```
diff --git a/.eslintrc.json b/.eslintrc.json
index 3badf81f..2cd7119b 100644
--- a/.eslintrc.json
+++ b/.eslintrc.json
@@ -14,3 +14,4 @@
         "browser": true,
-        "node": true
+        "node": true,
+        "es6": true
     },
@@ -42,3 +43,3 @@
         "dot-location": ["error", "property"],
-        "dot-notation": ["error", {"allowKeywords": false}],
+        "dot-notation": ["error", {"allowKeywords": true}],
         "eol-last": ["error", "always"],
@@ -168,3 +169,3 @@
         "no-restricted-syntax": "off",
-        "no-return-assign": "error",
+        "no-return-assign": ["error", "except-parens"],
         "no-return-await": "error",
@@ -284,3 +285,3 @@
         "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": ["error", {"when": "multiline", "maximum": 1}],
-        "react/jsx-no-bind": "warn",
+        "react/jsx-no-bind": ["warn", {"ignoreRefs": true}],
         "react/jsx-no-comment-textnodes": "warn",
@@ -326,3 +327,3 @@
         "react/sort-comp": [
-            2,
+            0,
             {
@@ -331,2 +332,4 @@
                     "static-methods",
+                    "state",
+                    "properties",
                     "lifecycle",
@@ -345,6 +348,5 @@
                     "lifecycle": [
-                        "constructor",
                         "getDefaultProps",
                         "getInitialState",
-                        "state",
+                        "constructor",
                         "getChildContext",
```

In order to visualize it with an "see collapsed code" functionality, I must try to determine whether there are any content after the last line of diff (the `"getChildContext",` line), is there any reliable method to archive this?

Comment: Could you explain what is meant with *content after the last line*? If you need to see more context you could increase it with the -U *N* option.

Comment: @yacc For example we have a file with 1000 lines of code, the diff shows some additions and deletions between L300 and L400, with the only input of the diff, I want to know if the original file has any code after L400. The `-U N` option can append some more lines around each diff chunk, but still I can't determine the exact value of `N`

Comment: There's a diff option `-D X` that produces a C-preprocessor styled merge file. `#ifdef X <left> #else <right> #endif <common part>`. But that option isn't supported by git diff.

Comment: There is no way to tell where the end of a file is in the diff. (Save a no newline message, but that's considered bad practice) Can you tell us what your end goal is? It sounds as though you may be trying to solve a problem with diff that is better handled with another tool.

Comment: @LightBender I'm developing a diff view component which can "show collapsed code between diff chunks", the problem is the last diff chunk doesn't hint whether there are more code after it. I can of course solve this by reading the file and add a `totalLines` to my API, but it's more complicated and performance hits (by reading file or preprocess and store lines count)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're going for. Why not just always show an expansion at the end of the last diff chunk? The vast majority of the time you'll need it anyway. I assume you want to only read in the part of the time you need when you expand for performance reasons? You might find that method will result in a much larger cumulative performance hit than just pulling in the entire file once and preprocessing it as a stream. You'd have to do some testing.